# Generalizing this pattern to 'n' lines

Tags: java, loops, console

For a homework assignment, I need help with generalizing the code for printing the following pattern.

```
   A
  B C  
 D E F 
G H I J
```

The problem was coding the spaces between the alphabets.
This is what i came up with, but it is just for the first 4 lines of the pattern.
(Sorry i have poor formatting skills >.>)

```
int r = 65;
char m ;
int count=0;
for(int i = 4;i>0;i--)
{
    for( int j = i;j>0;j--)
        {System.out.print(" ");}
    for(int j = 4-i;j>=0;j--)
        {
             count++;
             m=(char)r;
             if(count == 3||count == 6||count == 8 || count == 11|| count == 13|| count ==15)
             {
                 System.out.print(" ");r--; 

             }
                 else
                     System.out.print(m);r++;
        }
    for(int j = 4-i;j>0;j--)
        {
            count++;m=(char)r;
            if(count == 3||count == 6||count == 8 || count == 11|| count == 13|| count ==15)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");r--;
            }
                    else
                        System.out.print(m);r++;
        }                                                                               
            System.out.println("");
}
```

thanks to Gene for the explanation, i did some editing and this is what i came up with.

```
            int r = 65;
char m ;
for(int i = 4;i>0;i--)
    {
        for( int j = i;j>0;j--)
            {System.out.print(" ");}
        for(int j = 4-i;j>=0;j--)
    {
         m=(char)r;

            System.out.print(m+" ");
            r++;
    }
            System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: One big thing you could do to simplify the code is to use a StringBuilder and just print it all out at the end. It would also be more generic that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing loops is all about using math (usually simple math) to describe one iteration  in terms of loop indicies.

Let `N` be the number of rows so `i=0,1,...N-1` are their indices.

First, your example shows that row `i` has `N-i-1` leading spaces. Let's check this. For row `i=N-1` we get zero and for `i=0` we get `N-1`. In your example the `i=0` case is 3.  This agrees with the drawing, so we're looking good.

The second part is that there are `i+1` characters per row.  All but the last has a following space.  The last has a following newline.

Finally, we can get the correct letter by just starting at A and incrementing each time we print a new one.

So now we're ready to write code:

```
char ltr = 'A';
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

  // Print the leading spaces.
  int nLeadingSpaces = N - i - 1;
  for (int j = 0; j < nLeadingSpaces; j++) 
    System.out.print(' ');

  // Print the letters for this row.  There are
  // i+1 of them. So print the first i with a following
  // space and the last one with a newline.
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
    System.out.print(ltr++ + " ");
  System.out.println(ltr++);
}
```

This is untested but ought to work.

Comment: thanks i edited my code like how you explained and it worked :)

Comment: Homework is **not** supposed to be answered in full. That is why is was tagged [tag:homework].

Comment: I've taught CS for over 20 years. The guy obviously worked hard to get where he got. All that was left was generalizing his thinking from hard coded numbers to variables.  It often takes an example to get over this hump.  He did 85% of the assignment.

Answer (score -1):

You need two (nested) loops.

The outer for the line number.

The inner for the position in the line.

You need a variable defined outside the loops for the current character.

At the beginning of the inner loop write empty spaces according to max line - current line number * const (figure out the const yourself).

In the inner loop output the current character and a space.

At the end of inner loop increase the output character.

At the end of the outer loop proceed to the next line.

Comment: well i know i am bad but i am still learning and trying to get better..and what you said was a bit harsh..

Comment: Sorry, but this is an elementary assignment. My intention was not to insult you, but instead to spare you years of frustration.